# Random jQuery Dom Accesses Are Failing -- Out of Ideas

Tags: jquery, dom

Randomly, while doing a normal valid query, we're seeing oddities.

I've traced it some lines in jQuery1.6.4 (tried 1.7.2 as well with same results). Line #4737 (makeArray).

I've linked to two images, the first the expected case with the second being the error case, highlighting the variable result.

The expected case is a simple jquery object while the second is not. It looks like the dom document element? Not 100% sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm totally out of ideas on what we could be doing to cause this eror in jQuery :( This issue is intermittent and only occurs about 50% of the time.

It doesn't seem to be any particular element on the page. All elements that interact with jQuery can trigger this.

**Note: This is only happening in Chrome 18+. Doesn't happen in older versions of Chrome or FF/Safari.**

*Expected:*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyXMg.png

*Error:*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/372kU.png

Updating my post with further information. Below is an image with a valid result and a very odd result. As you can see, it's NOT a jquery object and instead is just "object" with a selector that is the FUNCTION call along with selector string....

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri5km.png

Comment: Do you have a code sample that you can reproduce this consistently with?

Comment: To clarify: it appears that sometimes jquery/sizzle looses the handle to the document object. Once that happens all future jquery/sizzle operations fail. (I work in the office with bobber205.) The page is massive and we've been trying unsuccessfully to create a reproducible demo outside of the page.

Comment: The information you've given us is unlikely to be sufficient for us to have any idea what's going on.  Can you point us to an actual web page and an actual piece of jQuery code that has this problem?  Or, even better, can you reproduce the problem in a small jsFiddle with just the relevant HTML, CSS and Javascript?

Comment: I've tried for days to come up with a test case in jsfiddle to no avail. I know it'd be requested and I made a huge effort to come up with one before posting.

Comment: any console errors when it fails?

Comment: Are there additional plugins or other javascript libraries that are being used on the page? Perhaps there is some conflict or bug in one of those. It could explain why you haven't been able to reproduce it in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a transport-level error in fetching the images and the `.load()` fails for that elements. `img` elements do have a `load` event that you can play with and inspect further.

Additionally,

> The hardware configuration of the Web server determines the
>   maximum file size that can successfully be sent in an HTTP resppnse.